# sequelize where on assosiated model

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have three Models User, Group, UserGroup. User and Group have many to many relations through UserGroup model. **I want to get groups with all of there group members But also want only those groups that a user is a member of**. Here is my sequelize query.

```
        Group.findAll({
            include: ['members'],
            where: {
                '$members.id$': user_id
            }
        });
```

With where condition in the above code the groups gets filtered according to user_id. ie. It returns groups related to User model with id equals to user_id. But this query is not giving all the members. it only returns one user that has id equals to user_id. That means the "where" condition is not only filtering the groups, it is also filtering the group members.

Here are my associations

```
Group.hasMany(UserGroup, {as: {singular: 'usergroup', plural: 'usergroups'}, foreignKey: 'group_id'});
Group.belongsToMany(User, {as: {singular: 'member', plural: 'members'}, through: UserGroup});

UserGroup.belongsTo(User, {as: 'member', foreignKey: 'user_id'});
UserGroup.belongsTo(Group, {as: 'group', foreignKey: 'group_id'});
```

Comment: Can you show code define model Group & User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try it and let me know :)

```
Group.findAll({
  include: ['members'],
  where:{
      id: {
          $in: sequelize.literal(`(select distinct group_id from usergroup where user_id = ${user_id})`)
      }
  }
})
.then(results => {
  console.log(results);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log('err', err);
});
```